# Text on taskbar using c# in .net window application

Tags: c#, .net, text, window, taskbar

How we Display a text on taskbar using .net window application with c#

i searched in Google but it displays 
 http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shubham0987/display-app-in-full-screen-with-windows-taskbar/

Please can anyone suggest. Thankyou

Comment: If you mean the windows taskbar: Space there is extremely precious. Why would you want, even dare to waste it with text???

Comment: I think you need to more clearly describe exactly what you want to acheive